# Assigning an array value to a variable in VBA causes my UDF to exit

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I can't seem to figure out why this UDF is exiting on the `currentInput = inputArray(i)`. Here is the relevant code:

```
Function OrderRange(inputRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim length As Integer
    inputHeight = inputRange.Count

    Dim inputArray As Variant
    inputArray = inputRange

    Dim strippedArray() As Variant
    ReDim strippedArray(0 To (inputHeight - 1))

    Dim currentInput As String

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To (inputHeight - 1)

        currentInput = inputArray(i)
        '...computations on currentInput...'
        strippedArray(i) = currentInput
    Next i
    OrderRange = strippedArray
End Function
```

The debugger reaches `currentInput = inputArray(i)` but once I move to the next line, the function terminates and a `#VALUE!` error is entered into the cell I call the function from. I know this is a specific question, but I'm sure it's a general issue and I'll edit this original post to reflect what the general problem is.

**Edit:** This is an issue regarding assignment of a range to a variant array.

Comment: You shoud use `Option Explicit`. Here you didn't, so you ended up declaring a variable and not using it (`length`), and implicitly declaring `inputHeight` as a Variant.

Comment: Good catch, Jean, I modified the code for the post for clarity of my question; I forgot to change "length" to "inputHeight".

Comment: Yup, that's a classic... That's why people use `Option Explicit`: it won't *let* you forget!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variant arrays created by setting them equal to ranges have two dimensions even if they are only one column, or row, wide.  So if you call the function with A1:A10 you'll get a 10 * 1 array.  Also the lower bound of the dimensions will be one, not zero.  So you'd have to do something like:

```
For i = 1 To (inputHeight)
    currentInput = inputArray(i, 1)
```

Also you should use Option Explicit so that you're reminded to declare all variables.  InputHeight is never declared.

Comment: Or use `Application.Transpose` to force a single dimension variant (if the range is one column or one row)